# Acceder a elemento, lista de lista - Python

Tags: python, loops

Muy buenas, soy nuevo en Python y estoy ahora luchando con las listas.

Os expongo lo que tengo desarrollado.

Actualmente tengo un programa que a través de un archivo .csv me carga la siguiente estructura de datos.

```
1,4.0,?,?,none,?
2,2.0,3.0,?,none,38
2,2.5,2.5,?,tc,39
```

Posteriormente lo almaceno en una lista, aplicando un split en las comas de manera que me queda una lista con la siguinte forma.

```
['1', '4.0', '?', '?', 'none', '?\n']
['2', '2.0', '3.0', '?', 'none', '38\n']
['2', '2.5', '2.5', '?', 'tc', '39\n']
```

En base a esa lista tengo que calcular la media, de los elementos en cada columna, es decir, la media por ejemplo del primero sería con los elementos 1 , 2 y 2, la segunda media con los elementos 4.0 2.0 y 2.5 y así sucesivamente.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿ cómo acceder a esos elementos ? , hasta ahora estaba haciendo un for de la lista, pero me devolvía cada fila, es decir,
['1', '4.0', '?', '?', 'none', '?\n'] y así sucesivamente, pero tras probar de distintas maneras, no consigo que me devuelva el primero de los elementos de cada una de las filas, luego el segundo y así sucesivamente hasta que terminen los caracteres.

Tengo la siguiente función a la que le paso la lista a tratar, anteriormente comentada.

Para posteriormente obtener los elementos de la primera columna, luego la segunda y así sucesivamente.

```
def promedio(lista):
    for elem in lista:
        print elem

def main():
print sys.argv[1]
lista = []

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       lista.append(line.split(','))
print f.close()
lista.pop()
True

promedio(lista)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

En definitiva, es un main, que realiza el procesado de datos y posteriormente pasa la lista a una función que calcula el promedio de los valores numéricos (todavía no desarrollada).

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola fiticida. ¿Que pasa con los `none` y `?`?¿Los tratas como 0 o los ignoras en el cálculo de la media? También es importante que agregues el código con el que lees actualmente el csv. ¿Puedes usar otros módulos como [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) de la biblioteca estándar o externos como Pandas?

Comment: Sí, disculpa, ahora actualizo el post principal, respecto lo que dices, correcto, ignoro esos valores a la hora de tomar la media.

Comment: son 3 listas diferentes o es una matriz en donde tienes esos valores?

Comment: Es una única lista que tiene 3 filas, como tu dices, una matriz.

Comment: Probaste leer el cvs usando directamente la libreria que python provee para leer estos archivos [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) asi evitas los salto de linea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usa [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) o `itertools.izip` (retorna un iterador en Python 2.x como hace `zip` en Python 3) para obtener las columnas de forma simple. Si le pasas una serie de iterables retornará una lista de tuplas emparejando los elementos que están en la misma posición.

Para desempaquetar las listas anidas se usa el operador `*`.

Para que no se te incluyan los saltos de línea en la última columna usa el método `str.strip()`:

```
import sys 

def promedio(lista):
    columnas = zip(*lista)
    for columna in columnas:
        print(columna)

def main():
    lista = []
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            lista.append(line.strip().split(','))
    promedio(lista)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Que nos da la siguiente salida:

> ('1', '2', '2')
>   ('4.0', '2.0', '2.5')
>   ('?', '3.0', '2.5')
>   ('?', '?', '?')
>   ('none', 'none', 'tc')
>   ('?', '38', '39')

Otra opción es usar `for` anidados y acceder a los elementos mediante índexación:

```
def promedio(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista[0])):
        columna = [fila[i] for fila in lista]
        print(columna)
```

Cuando se usa el estamento `with` (manejador de contexto) no tienes que cerrar tu el archivo de forma explícita, eso ya se hace de forma automática.

---

Hay varias formas de calcular la media, lo primero es pasar los valores a `float`. Aquellos que no puedan ser pasados como si quieres tenerlos en cuenta para la media podemos hacer que sean 0. Podemos hacerlo con una pequeña función.

Una posibilidad es la siguiente:

```
import sys 
import itertools


def promedio(lista):
    media =  [sum(columna)/len(columna) for columna in itertools.izip(*lista)]
    print(media)


def to_float(string):
    try:
        return float(string)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

def main():
    lista = []
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
        lista = [[to_float(valor) for valor in line.strip().split(',')] for line in f]
    promedio(lista)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Esto nos nos genera una lista con las medias de cada columna:

> [1.6666666666666667, 2.8333333333333335, 1.8333333333333333, 0, 0, 25.666666666666668]

Enlace para reproducir online: https://repl.it/Na3Y/2

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias, es una solución muy buena. La cosa que me  estoy perdiendo a la hora de acceder a los valores, es decir, ahora tengo mis valores ('1','2','2'), ¿como podría obtener cada uno de ellos para el cálculo de la media? ya que me lo devuelve en conjunto

Comment: Seria algo similar a esto, #lista2.append(a + ... + n / len(columna)), siendo el sumatorio los elementos 1 2 2 de la primera fila por ejemplo, pero no sabría como incluir dichos valores para realizar el sumatorio, lo almaceno en una nueva lista que he creado, para posteriormente mostrarlo todo de una.

Comment: fiticia si me dices como quieres tratar los ? y nones te doy un ejemplo de como hacerlo. Para obtener cada valor basta conanidar dos for: `for columna in columnas:` y debajo `for valor in columna:`.

Comment: Tanto los ?, como los nones, los ignoramos a la hora de realizar la media, sin embargo si cuentan para el divisor, es decir, supongamos el siguiente ejemplo, con la columna {'1','2','?'), sumaria 3 y habría que dividirlo entre los 3 elementos que conforman la columna, es decir en este caso la media sería 1, (3 entre 3), otro ejemplo, {'none','?', '1'} seria 1 es decir la suma de los elementos que no son ni none ni ?, entre los tres elementos que conforman la columna, en este caso daría 1/3 = 0.333

Comment: Sí sin problema,

Comment: fiticia he editado la respuesta, échale un vistazo.

Comment: Me debería funcionar correctamente, pero unicamente me está mostrando un valor que es [1.25] y eso que he replicado el código tal cual me indicas.

Comment: He probado el código con tu csv e imprime la lista completa, algo se escapa. He creado un ejemplo online que puedes ejecutar (solo cambia que no recibe el csv como argumento): https://repl.it/Na3Y/2. Puedes ejecutarlo, comprobar el csv y el código.

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias, debe ser un problema de mi IDE, muchísimas gracias de verdad, una tutorial muy instructiva, gracias que hay gente como tú, un saludo